# is it possible to upgrade postgresql from 9.4 to 13.3 using pg_upgrade?

Tags: windows, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-13, pg-upgrade

When i try to Upgrade 9.4 to 13 using pg_upgrade ,  the Upgrade stops in between with authentication failure using the password from pgpass.conf file .

The same approach works from 9.4 to 9.6

Here is the pg_upgrade command that i used

```
C:\postgresql\13\bin\pg_upgrade --old-datadir C:/PostgreSQL/9.4/data --new-datadir C:/PostgreSQL/13/data --old-bindir C:/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin --new-bindir C:/PostgreSQL/13/bin --old-port=5433 --new-port=5435 --username <superusername> --verbose
```

I am running this command from %temp%

Comment: I doubt that this is your real command line.  You didn't specify a username for the `--username` option.  Well you do, but it is accidently the very odd username "--verbose".  And why are you specifying port numbers?

Comment: i have specified a superusername . . . i just didnt post it here.  when i dont specify the port numbers , the pg_upgrade is considering 5432 as old port. So i had to specify the port

Comment: pg_upgrade should default to port 50432, not 5432.  Do you have environment variables such as PGPORTNEW from some previous work left over polluting your environment ?

Answer (score 0):

To do the migration, I used logical replication using the server with version 9.4 to replicate to a server with version 13.
Another option would be to migrate using pg_dumpall and pg_restore.